# Transparency works in sample file, but not in mine with same settings?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency

See attached screenshot.  Blender model on the left is my very simple scene, with a basic cylinder underneath a plane.  The cylinder is shaded with a solid color, and the plane is supposed to be glass.  But all I'm getting from the glass is reflection, no transmission.

I thought it was an issue with my settings or something, so I downloaded the "ripple dreams" blender sample file, which has water in it as a sample transparent material.  I compared settings, which you can see in the screenshots - the render settings are in the top right of each blender window, the material settings are in the bottom left.  You can see that the material previous in both cases looks correct, but it's not correct in the viewport.  Viewport is set to "Material Preview" in both cases, and the rendered settings doesn't help at all.  The only difference is that I set "Refraction Depth" to a non-zero value because my plane is 2D, and the water is 3D (i guess?).

So I can't find a difference in settings.  Both are rendered in eevee.  If I set my file to cycles and render, then I get transparency, so it must be some eevee setting.

I also tried using the recommended settings in [this guide](https://artisticrender.com/how-to-use-alpha-transparent-textures-in-blender/).

Can someone help me understand why my transparency isn't working in eevee?

[image]

Comment: For transparency to work in EEVEE, you must "enable it" in the material properties. In the bottom right of your image, where it says "Blend Mode" (Currently Opaque) , change it to Alpha-Blend, or Alpha-Hashed

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I tried that just now and it had no effect on the viewport display.  Also wonder why the "ripple dreams" sample works with those set at "Opaque"?

Comment: Actually what @ChristopherBennett says is not completely correct. Or, to be more precise, he is correct that you need to set it to _Alpha Blend/Hashed_ if you want alpha transparency (so for example if the _Alpha_ value on the _Principled BSDF_ was lower than 1), but it doesn't make anything transparent if you are using _Transmission_, which is set on the _Principled BSDF_ and which is what a _Glass BSDF_ uses.

Comment: The setting that makes transmissive materials see-through is _Screen Space Refraction_, which means transmissive materials without enabled refraction are not "transparent" when no objects are behind them - so the transparency of the object on the right side is more like an "illusion" since it's not really transparent but refracting what is below. The only problem now is (hence I'm not writing a proper answer) when I look at your setting, the glass should show the object below as well, so maybe we need the file to inspect where the difference lies.